# Angular JS Restrict ng-click events in the same div

Tags: angularjs

Both functions are triggered while I click on the inner a tag, how can I restrict this. I need to trigger onDelete() function only when  is clicked

```
<div ng-click="ctrl.onEdit()">
{{content}}
<a href="" ng-click="ctrl.onDelete()" > Delete Me !</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot to close the first ng-click with "

Comment: So don't wrap `<a>` that has `ngClick` with a parent element that also got it. Wrap `{{content}}` with span: `<span ng-click="ctrl.onEdit()">{{content}}</span>` (and remove the `ngClick` form the div)

Answer (score 1):

Pass the $event in ctrl.onDelete($event) and then stop propagating it in the on delete function, you need this because events bubble towards parent elements

```
 this.onDelete = function (event){
             event.stopPropagation(); 
 }
```

or simply write this after you ondelete function in html

```
ng-click="ctrl.onDelete(); $event.stopPropagation();"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achive that by passing `$event` and use `stopPropagation`:

```
<div ng-click="onEdit($event)" style="background-color:red;">
  {{content}}
   <a href="" ng-click="onDelete($event)" > Delete Me !</a>
 </div>
```

*JS*

```
$scope.onEdit = function(event){
    console.log("onEdit");
    event.stopPropagation();        
  }

  $scope.onDelete = function(){
    console.log("onDelete");
    event.stopPropagation();        
  }
```

<kbd>[Demo Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5qu5mpXOHzwmImLmh49X?p=preview)</kbd>

---

However its not good practice to use nested `ng-click`. Its hard to maintain and can lead to unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-click="ctrl.onEdit()">
        {{content}}
</div>
<div>
 <a href="" ng-click="ctrl.onDelete()" > Delete Me !</a>
</div>
```

I think it will work like this

Comment: I don't like this solution. The first `div` element should be a `span`. And the second one is unnecessary.

Comment: It is a solution. In his code the <a> tag is a child of <div> so both function called when click on child. In my solution both are separated

Answer (score 0):

It's called [event bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing). You can propagate the the event and cancel it like this

```
function onDelete($event){
   if($event){
      if ($event.stopPropagation) $event.stopPropagation();
      if ($event.preventDefault) $event.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div ng-click="ctrl.onEdit()">
     {{content}}
     <a href="" ng-click="ctrl.onDelete($event)" > Delete Me !</a>
 </div>
```